# Class Organization: How to call instance members in other classes while organizaing classes in folders

Tags: c#

I am attempting to organize my classes into folders as depicted in the image below:

The problem is when I run the main program, I get nothing, I am accessing the data members but cannot get their values.

There are three folders: `Asset`, `Transit` and `Members`.

Asset is the root folder. Members contain all variables that I need to access throughout the program and Transit holds other methods or a database class.

**Code:**

```
namespace ClassObjects.Asset.Members
{
    class DataMembers
    {
        private string instanceMemberA;
        private string instanceMemberB;

        public void SetValues(string inputA, string inputB)
        {
            this.instanceMemberA = inputA;
            this.instanceMemberB = inputB;
        }

        public string MemberA
        {
            get
            {
                return this.instanceMemberA;
            }
        }

        public string MemberB
        {
            get
            {
                return this.instanceMemberB;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

*Transit class:*

```
namespace ClassObjects.Asset.Transit
{
    class Transit
    {   
       //Example here
        public void DoNothing()
        {
         Asset.Members.DataMembers dataMember = new Asset.Members.DataMembers();

        //Pass values to datamember
            dataMember.SetValues("ValueA", "ValueB");
        }

    }
}
```

*Main Method:*

```
namespace ClassObjects
{
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       Asset.Members.DataMembers dataMember = new Asset.Members.DataMembers();

    //Unable to print the values sent to the data members from the Transit class.

    Console.WriteLine(dataMember.MemberA);

     Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn to use the debugger so that you can figure out when is happening by yourself! That's a very important skill to learn if you want to program.

Anyway, in your case: your main program performs only 2 steps:

1. It `new DataMembers()`. This calls the default constructor (you have none), which means all your fields will have their default value. For a string it's `null`.
2. It prints `dataMember.MemberA`. As I said at this point the value is `null` and `null` prints nothing on your console.

So that's expected behavior. I guess you are missing a `SetValues()` call somewhere. BTW your `Transit` class is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is behaving as expected. Did you mean to make `Transit` return a collection of data?

```
public Asset.Members.DataMembers DoNothing()
{
    var dataMember = new Asset.Members.DataMembers();

    // Pass values to datamember
    dataMember.SetValues("ValueA", "ValueB");

    // Return values to the caller
    return dataMember;
}
```

Then, in your program, store the result of that method and print that instead.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        Asset.Members.DataMembers dataMember;

        dataMember = new Transit().DoNothing();

        Console.WriteLine(dataMember.MemberA);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```